# Mais de uma model em uma página razor .net6

Tags: razor, view, relacionamento, model

estou desenvolvendo um sistema de cadastro, simples (eu acho) seguindo um tutorial, mas como tenho algum conhecimento de banco de dados, consegui com algum trabalho entender e realizar alguns passos de relacionamento de tabelas, mas agora que fazer a View capturar e apresentar os dados usados no banco, quando é uma única tabela, tranquilão, uso o "@model NomeDaClasse", funciona, entretanto, preciso usar mais de uma tabela (usando 5 na verdade). Eu gostaria de saber como fazer para vincular mais de uma model em uma viewr que capture e apresente os dados do banco.
Obrigado,

Comment: crie uma view com todas as propriedades que precisa, depois vai no banco recupera todos os dados e passa para a classe e usa na view... note que não é obrigado a usar a classe do banco direto na view.... classes de banco são uma coisa, classes para o view podem ser diferentes para atender cada necessidade separado

Comment: OK, entendi a ideia no caso das classes de uso de banco serem diferentes das classes de uso nas views, mas acho que não fui tão claro.
Criei uma view de formulário, nela tem dados de uma pessoa a serem cadastradas: nome, nasc, sexo, prof e endereço. Nome, sexo e prof coloquei em uma tabela chamada pessoa, endereço (logradouro, numero bairro, etc) coloquei em uma tabela chamada endereço.
Para salvar as informações preciso por o @model lá em cima, para conseguir guardar os dados, é isso que não estou conseguindo fazer. 
Agradeço a disponibilidade.

Answer (score -2):

Consegui, muito obrigado Ricardo.
Criei uma nova Model, inseri as model em questão conforme você orientou.

Haviam as Model PessoaModel e EnderecoModel, criei uma classe PessoaEndereco, mas mesmoassim, precisei fazer toda a configuração de um anova model, Controller, Contexto, program.cs, interfaces, em fim, como uma model noraml, entretanto consegui a partir desta acessar os atributos a partir dela.